# Include non-column value in sqlalchemy query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How do I do this in sqlalchemy `SELECT column1, 'Table1' as TableName
FROM Table1`?

Specifically the `'Table1' as TableName` part.

I want this so that I can know which table a row came from in a union query I am doing. Apologies if this should be simple but I spent at least an hour trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `literal_column`:

```
select([t1.c.col1, literal_column("t1", type_=Unicode).label("TableName")])
```

Comment: Not sure whether I should accept this answer, maybe if you edit it? 

I had to use `bindparam("TableName", "t1")` in my query because using `literal_column` resulted in errors like this:

`ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) column "t1" does not exist
LINE 1: ...d AS relations_id, relations.time_linked AS time, t1 AS tabl...`

However your post led me me in the right direction.

Comment: It seems that I did not guess what is you table like correctly. I edited the post.

Comment: Actually, many apologies Bartosz, you were correct. I was getting the error because I didn't specify the Unicode type. (when I tried to do that I got Unicode not defined errors, but I now realize I had to simply import the Unicode column type). 

Sorry for making you re-edit, but can revert your response back to your initial answer. (Maybe include the imports as well to be less confusing to other newbies)

Comment: No problem, I reverted it.